# Processing time windows doesn't work on finite data sources in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to apply a very simple window function to a finite data stream in Apache Flink (*locally, no cluster*). Here's the example:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env
  .fromCollection(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))

  .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
  .trigger(ProcessingTimeTrigger.create)
  .process(new ProcessAllWindowFunction[String, String, TimeWindow] {
    override def process(context: Context, elements: Iterable[String], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
      out.collect(elements.toList.sorted.toString())
    }
  })

  .print()

env.execute()
```

Here, I try to group all the elements that arrive into the window within a second and then just print these groups.

I assumed that all the elements would be produces in much less than one second and get into one window, so there will be one incoming element in `print()`. However, **nothing is printed** at all when I run this.

If I remove all the windowing stuff, like

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env
  .fromCollection(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
  .print()
```

I see the elements printed after the run. I also tried this with the file source, no difference.

The default parallelism on my machine is 6. If I experiment with the level of parallelism and delays, like this

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(2)
env
  .fromCollection(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
  .map { x => Thread.sleep(1500); x }
```

I able to get some--not all--elements into groups, which are printed.

My first assumption is that the source finishes much faster than 1 second and the task is shut down before the window's timer fires. Debugging showed that [the timer setting line in `ProcessingTimeTrigger`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/8674b69964eae50cad024f2c5caf92a71bf21a09/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/triggers/ProcessingTimeTrigger.java#L36) is reached. Shouldn't all started timers finish before a task shuts down (at least this is the impression I got from [the code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/8674b69964eae50cad024f2c5caf92a71bf21a09/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/tasks/StreamTask.java#L327))?

Could you please help me understand this and make this more deterministic?

**Update #1, 23.09.2018:**

I also experimented with event time windows instead of processing time windows. If I do this:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env
  .fromCollection(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor[String] {
    override def extractAscendingTimestamp(element: String): Long = {
      element.charAt(0).toInt
    }
  })

  .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
  .trigger(EventTimeTrigger.create)
  .process(new ProcessAllWindowFunction[String, String, TimeWindow] {
    override def process(context: Context, elements: Iterable[String], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
      out.collect(elements.toList.toString())
    }
  })

  .print()

env.execute()
```

Then again nothing is printed. The debugger shows that the trigger's `onElement` is called for every element, but `onEventTime` is never called.

Also, if I modify the the timestamp extractor to make bigger steps:

```
element.charAt(0).toInt * 1000
```

all the elements are printed (one element per group, which is expected), apart from the last.

**Update #2, 23.09.2018:**

Update #1 is answered in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467413/processing-time-windows-doesnt-work-on-finite-data-sources-in-apache-flink?noredirect=1#comment91879894_52467413).

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify the triggering, since you are using the default triggers in each case.

Comment: When working with event time you have to include  env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

Comment: Great, now it works.
Does it mean that only one time characteristic might be in use in an environment? What if I need to process another stream in the processing time manner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a finite source reaches the end, if you are using event time then a Watermark with timestamp Long.MAX_VALUE will be injected, which will cause all event time timers to fire. However, with processing time, Flink will wait for all currently firing timers to complete their actions, and then exit.

As you suspected, you're not seeing any output because the source finishes very quickly.

Deterministic behavior is straightforward with event time processing; with processing time it's not really achievable.

But here's a hack that more or less works:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val s = env.fromCollection(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
val t = env.addSource((context: SourceContext[String]) => {
  while(true) {
    Thread.sleep(100)
    context.collect("dummy")
  }
})

s.union(t)
  .filter(_ != "dummy")
  .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
  .process(new ProcessAllWindowFunction[String, String, TimeWindow] {
    override def process(context: Context, elements: Iterable[String], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
      out.collect(elements.toList.sorted.toString())
    }
  })
  .print()

env.execute()
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer and for the hach. As for the event time, please, see the update in the post.

Comment: After [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467413/processing-time-windows-doesnt-work-on-finite-data-sources-in-apache-flink#comment91879894_52467413), it seems to work! Thank you, David!

Comment: Thanks both for the question and responses, as I was having the same confusion. So David's saying that because the source completes, and the Window hasn't started firing, it will terminate before getting that chance? Is that intended behaviour? I also tried setting allowedLateness to no avail, but I assume for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

David's answer is quite straightforward!
I have tried ways to handle finite stream with ProcessTime or GlobalWindows. All faced the issue of how to end this job properly(source stop, operator processed all data, sink done). Because processtime and count window will just leave the window/data unprocessed like David's answer. One way is to sync communition between source and operator and then notify to exit. But it's not beautiful. So just simply choose EventTime window which will have all data processed even after stop the source at first beginning.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible code with your answer?